# How to parse multipart/mixed content from JSP to servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm sending **multipart/mixed** content message from JSP to servlets but when I used

> ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

method to check if the request is Multipart or not, I'm getting the output as "false". This is how content type  header of my message is looking like:

```
multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_26_2184190.1271924416255"
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I parse the request using Apache fileupload API? How the above method can return me an output as "true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are:

- the request method must be `post`
- the content-type must start with `multipart/`

Check these two via `request.getMethod()` and `request.getContentType()`